# How to create changing content in JSF 2.0 Panel

Tags: jsf-2

I'm trying to create something that would have the looks of a tabbed interface in JSF 2.0.

I can use myfaces and richfaces (either, neither or both) to do this.

I've done something similar in jsf 1.2 with backing bean code that actually removed the panel contents and replaced it with the current selection but I think there has to be a better way to do it.

The general looks should be something like this:
[image]

The Question - What's the best method of changing the central panel's contents according to the panel button that was pushed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rich:panelMenu](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/panelMenu.jsf?c=panelMenu&tab=usage) will work for you

Comment: Tnx. I'm leaving this open to see if there are more options, perhaps without using richfaces.
I'll mark it as the answer if this is the best option.